# Was this exchange between Captain America and Thor inspired from the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

During the final battle in *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Captain America picks up Mjolnir.

Amidst the battle, Captain America,

> calls [presumably] Stormbreaker and Mjolnir goes to Thor.

At this moment, they have a short exchange of sorts (following up to the one in *Avengers: Infinity War*) where Thor says to Cap:

> **Thor**: *No, give me that. You have the little one.* 
>  
>  [image: Cap and Thor swap Mjolnir and Stormbreaker]
>   <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Was this scene inspired from the comics?

I remember seeing something like this, but I can’t seem to find it anywhere now.

Details that might help- it only involves Mjolnir, Cap is holding it and Thor seems to be asking it back.

Comment: From a look around I can't find any prior reference to it but I might be mistaken. Remember in the comics Stormbreaker belongs to Beta Ray Bill.

Comment: Yeah, i should edit the question actually. I remember there being just Mjolnir. And Captain America holding it while Thor asking it back.

Comment: There's [this](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-50O7Pw_byXw/WrtON5oWRrI/AAAAAAAAbbE/ctwQ82tRJAoqGBqwWrlav2zfVPZlg5tOwCHMYCw/s1600/RCO032.jpg) one where he gives it back to Jane Foster and the classic [one](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/V_Jh4FETXSE6FpQLVy9TN5rYrjs=/28x28:1590x1169/1200x675/filters:focal(749x159:1007x417)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63692365/IMG_A19F4B6FF306_1.0.jpeg) where Thor and Cap are both holding it but neither match particularly well.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the second image is what I was looking for. I was mistaken then I guess. But I think you could compose it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: the director's commentary indicates that this is just the final bit of character development for Thor. His entire arc has been around his worthiness and everyone's expectations, then his decline into guilt and ultimately fear around his not being worthy / failing. As he actualizes himself during the Dark World timeline visit, he's learned that the hammer nor his worthiness of it doesn't define him, and he's not threatened by Roger's worthiness of it either. Thor has become, not just who he needs to be, but who he wants to be.

Comment: I still laugh at that scene. lol :D

Comment: Well the director can say whatever they want but the fact that the weapons went to the wrong person cannot be explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from *Thor* Issue 390 when Captain America wields Mjolnir in order to give it back to Thor. Later on after the battle Thor and Cap both hold Mjolnir's handle whilst talking about the bond that now binds them. In particular the last panel appears to be what you are looking for.

[image: Thor and Cap hold Mjolnir together]